# Converting/Casting my Enum to Object in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

In my `GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)` I'm trying to return my `Role` property of the type `Role` which is an Enum.

```
public class RoleAttribute : DataAttribute
{
    public Role Role { get; set; }

    public RoleAttribute(Role role)
    {
        Role = role;
        AuthRespository.Login(role);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
        return Role.ToObject<List<object[]>>();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error saying:

> Error  CS0308  The non-generic method 'Enum.ToObject(Type, byte)' cannot be used with type arguments

`GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)` is an abstract member of the `DataAttribute` class.

Comment: I just want a way to return my `Role` I'm not sure how to do it in the GetData() method.

Comment: I have also tried to do `return new[] { Role };` in the GetData() method. However it tells me: `Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Reptune.Selenium.Enums.Role[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object[]>
`

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of the items in the enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the attribute perform functions (i.e. `AuthRespository.Login(role);`) aside,

Just have the `GetData` return the desired data

```
public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod) {
    yield return new object[] { Role };
}
```

or

```
public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod) {
    return new[] { new object[] { Role } };
}
```